# Harmonic Product Spectrum using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Im tying to find the fundamental frequency of a note using harmonic product spectrum. This is the part that implements the HPS algorithm

```
seg_fft = seg_fft(1 : size(seg_fft,1)/2 );  % FFT data
    seg_fft = abs(seg_fft);

    seg_fft2 = ones(size(seg_fft));
    seg_fft3 = ones(size(seg_fft));
    seg_fft4 = ones(size(seg_fft));
    seg_fft5 = ones(size(seg_fft));

    for i = 1:floor((length(seg_fft)-1)/2)
        seg_fft2(i,1) = (seg_fft(2*i,1) + seg_fft((2*i)+1,1))/2;
    end

for i = 1:floor((length(seg_fft)-2)/3)
        seg_fft3(i,1) = (seg_fft(3*i,1) + seg_fft((3*i)+1,1) + seg_fft((3*i)+2,1))/3;    
    end

for i = 1:floor((length(seg_fft)-3)/4)
        seg_fft4(i,1) = (seg_fft(4*i,1) + seg_fft((4*i)+1,1) + seg_fft((4*i)+2,1) + seg_fft((4*i)+3,1))/4;
    end

 for i = 1:floor((length(seg_fft)-4)/5)
        seg_fft5(i,1) = (seg_fft(5*i,1) + seg_fft((5*i)+1,1) + seg_fft((5*i)+2,1) + seg_fft((5*i)+3,1) + seg_fft((5*i)+4,1))/5;
    end

f_ym = (seg_fft) .* (seg_fft2) .* (seg_fft3)  .* (seg_fft4) .*(seg_fft5);
```

Now when i play F4, the 2nd harmonic(698 -F5) has a higher amplitude. So HPS is supposed to help me detect the fundamental which is F4 and NOT F5.
When i do the HPS these are the graphs I get:
[image: Plot of seg_fft2][image: seg_fft3]

[image: seg_fft4]

[image: seg_fft5]

The figures above show the plots of seg_fft2, seg_fft3, seg_fft4 and seg_fft5 respectively.

But what I dont understand is how come the frequency points obtained in these graphs are not factors of the original spectrum?? Isn't that how HPS is supposed to work??

This is the plot I obtained when I took the product of all 5.[image]

the peak is at 698Hz.. But shouldn't it be at 349Hz instead??

But after the whole code is run, I do get the fundamental as F4.. Its all very confusing.... Can someone tell me why my graphs are different from what is expected yet I get the correct fundamental please????

This is the rest of the code

```
    %HPS, PartIII: find max
     f_y1 = max(f_ym)

      for c = 1 : length(f_ym)
          if(f_ym(c,1) == f_y1)
              index = c;
          end
      end

      % Convert that to a frequency
      f_y(h) = (index / NFFT) * FS;

      h=h+1;

%end

V = abs(f_y);
```

Please do help...... Thanx in advance....